# CAEmitterLayer doesn't add basic animation if beginTime was set for it

Tags: ios, cabasicanimation, caanimation, caemitterlayer

I am trying to animate an explosion with `CAEmitterLayer` and a couple of `CAEmitterCell`. This should happen after a short delay after user sees a view. I start my animation in `viewDidAppear`.

Particle animation itself works fine, but as in this question [Initial particles from CAEmitterLayer don't start at emitterPosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994236/initial-particles-from-caemitterlayer-dont-start-at-emitterposition) unless I set `emitterLayer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()` animation appears to user as one that has been running for some time.

Now to actually achieve an explosion I have to stop emitting particles at some point. I try to use this code to setup `CABasicAnimation` which would stop emitter after some time:

```
// emitter layer is reused (remove all animations, remove all cells, remove from superlayer)
... // emitter layer setup in a function "explode" which is called from viewDidAppear
emitterLayer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()

let birthRateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "birthRate")
birthRateAnimation.toValue = 0
birthRateAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
birthRateAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1
birthRateAnimation.duration = 5
birthRateAnimation.delegate = self // (self is view controller)
birthRateAnimation.setValue("expl", forKey: "animName")

emitterLayer.add(birthRateAnimation, forKey: "birthRateAnimation")
self.view.layer.addSublayer(emitterLayer)
```

So now with this code `birthRateAnimation` is not actually triggered. I have logs in `animationDidStop` and `animationDidStart` which don't print anything.

Now, if I call `explode` function on button tap I see **no** particle animation at all, but in logs I see "animation start" / "animation stop" messages.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

I found two problems that kept the animation from working correctly.

1. The animation is on `birthRate`, but `CAEmitterLayer` does not have a `birthRate` property; `CAEmitterCell` does, though.  Give your `CAEmitterCell` a name and change `CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "birthRate")` to `CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "emitterCells.cellName.birthRate")`
2. Setting the beginTime to `CACurrentMediaTime() + 1.0` does not do what you want, because the emitter layer has its own time scale.  Changing that to `emitterLayer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) + 1.0` does what you want.

Comment: Your #1 is not correct. `CAEmitterLayer` does have a `birthRate`. The birth rates of all cells are multiplied with it.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I ran into the very same thing and the solution is to set `beginTime` of your emitter to `CACurrentMediaTime()`, e.g.:

```swift
let emitter = makeAwesomeEmitter()
emitter.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()

let emitterAnimation = makeAwesomeEmitterBirthRateAnimation()
emitterAnimation.beginTime = 1.0 // 1 sec delay
emitter.add(emitterAnimation, forKey: nil)

myView.layer.addSublayer(emitter)
```

Rationale is that the emitter pre-generates particles to imitate it running already for a while. See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29994236/172695) which brought me to the solution.